# Applying tier 2 visa after visitor visa refusal

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, refusal

I had previously applied for UK visitor visa from Saudi Arabia and it was refused on the grounds of my immigration history in Saudi Arabia . I am working on that part for the time being and am trying to change my residential status to an independent one .In the meanwhile , I am being offered a job in the UK and my employers have assured to provide me the certificate of sponsorship required for tier 2 visa , so that I can apply for a tier 2 visa . Keeping in view my prior history of UK visa refusal , what issues would I need to clarify to the entry clearance officer to avoid another visa refusal . Besides,would my prior refusal of UK visitor visa be a red flag while asssessing my subsequent application for tier 2 visa,in a sense that the ECO would look unfavorably at my application ,as someone trying to enter UK by any means and could that in any way affect my credibility as an applicant ?

Comment: All sorts of things will be taken into account, including previous immigration history. When did you apply for the visitors visa?

Comment: I applied in June 2015 for UK visitor visa

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question, the general grounds of refusal does consider conduct issues, as with all immigration applications because they need to ensure you would not be abusing the immigration system in the UK.

However you need to understand that the visit visas has different requirements then to the Tier 2 General.

Further to that, Tier 2 has a new policy where it considers the genuine vacancy test and applications can also be refused on those grounds.